# Как отсортировать два логически связанных массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть два логически связанных массива: `names` (имена) и `numbers` (номера телефонов).

Т.е. человеку с именем `names[10]` соответствует номер телефона `numbers[10]`.

Мне нужно получить 4 номера телефона людей с самыми короткими именами.

Comment: собрать пары имя, номер, отсортировать их по длине имен выбрать номера

Comment: @собрать пары в объект?

Comment: ага, чтобы было: [[имя, номер],[имя, номер]...]

Comment: @Grundy Зачем массив массивов делать то? Можно же просто объект состряпать.

Comment: Как выглядят элементы основного массива не важно, главное чтобы в них содержалось и имя и номер, тогда по ним можно будет сортировать и выбрать

Comment: @Grundy Массивы большие и код этот очень требователен к быстродействию. Я вот думаю что заместо сортировки быстрее будет просто прогнать массив и выдернуть 4 самых коротких имени.

Comment: можно сделать и так.

Answer (score 0):

Немного памяти отъест, но если не стоит задачи по оптимизации:

```js
var names = [
    'Andy',
    'Alexandr',
    'Any'
  ],

  phones = [
    '123',
    '456',
    '789'
  ],

  result = [];

for (var i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
  result.push({
    name: names[i],
    phone: phones[i]
  });
}

result = result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.length - b.name.length;
});

document.querySelector('#out').textContent = JSON.stringify(result, true, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

**Если надо оптимизировать:** (Хотя все равно одна копия массива будет)

```js
var names = [
    'Andy',
    'Alexandr',
    'Any'
  ],

  phones = [
    '123',
    '456',
    '789'
  ],

  result = [];


result = names.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.length - b.length;
}).slice(0, 2).map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    phone: phones[names.indexOf(name)]
  };
});

document.querySelector('#out').textContent = JSON.stringify(result, true, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

**Или**

Еще можно вручную в 2х циклах, в первом найти минимальную длину, во втором уже найти 4 телефона.

Comment: А если так https://jsfiddle.net/q71ooLkj/ ? Есть ошибки?